# Explain Java extends ... & syntax in angle brackets

Tags: java, generics

I honestly don't know what to google for:

```
public static <T extends Fragment & OnClickListener> SomeListFragment instantiate(
        T target, int requestCode, DataSource<ResultItem> dataSource, int position) {

    SomeListFragment fragment = new ExposeListFragment();

    return fragment;
}
```

It's in the SomeListFragment class.
I do understand that it's a static method to return a SomeListFragment (as a alternative to new SomeListFragment ()), but whats the stuff in the brackets?

```
<T extends Fragment & OnClickListener>
```

Comment: Search for `Generics in Java`.

Answer (score 2):

This is code that uses Generics.

In this case, you would declare your `SomeListFragment foo` as `SomeListFragement<T> foo` where T is a class that implements the interfaces `Fragment` and `OnClickListener`.  Then when you call `instantiate` you pass in an Object for the `target` argument that is of type `T`.

Answer (score 0):

The stuff in the brackets defines the generic type T that is used as the type for the target argument. It says that the type T can be any type that extends the Fragment class and implements the OnClickListener interface.

Google Java Generics for docs.

Answer (score 0):

Be careful! SomeListFragment has no generic parameter here! The only parametrized type is the `T target` reference. The programmer decided that this `target` reference should have implemented both `Fragment` and `OnClickListener` interfaces  (although he is not invoking/using any methods from `target` inside the method body).

Since it is a static method, this is the only way to do this. It could not be done declaring the class with generic parameters, since this is always tied with an instance.